# Connect USB device to android tablet in kiosk mode

Tags: android, usb

I have android tablet that should be in `kiosk mode` and fingerprint device `eNBioScan-C1`. I've found one problem and don't know the reason of it: when I use tablet in kiosk mode I cannot use fingerprint device. According to the log device is connected, but it is not initiate scanning. Once I turn to usual mode scanning work normally.

I'm not sure there is a problem in a code and furthermore all code of `fingerprint SDK` written in `C`, so I can see only names of methods that I use.

Maybe you have any idea why it can happen?